# Is this a correct implementation for a curried operator.add function?

Tags: python, functional-programming

This [blogpost](http://www.uncarved.com/blog/not_currying.mrk) proposed this implementation of a curried addition function:

```
def addN(n):
    return lambda x: x + n

def plus(a, b):
    addA=addN(a)
    return addA(b)
```

I believe my version is more correct because it uses unary functions all the way.

```
from operator import add
plus = lambda a: lambda b: add(a, b) 
plus(1)(2)
```

What do you think ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `plus` function is identical to the `addN` function from the blog post. The only differences are:

1. You used a `lambda` where the blog post used a `def`.
2. For some reason you used `operator.add(a,b)` instead of simply `a+b`.

Usage of `plus` and `addN` will give the same results so neither one is more "correct".

Note that the function naming you chose is confusing since your `plus` function corresponds to the `addN` function (rather than the `plus` function) from the blog post.